# How to handle null values on first render?

Tags: reactjs

I have a function which executes when the dropdown has a value of add or remove it will execute accordingly. However on the first render after I click the button it shows as 'added data'null. When I do it again it works. What would be the best way to handle this?

Here is my code:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I can't see any of the other code and there is no sandbox, I can only help you fix the issue of checking for null, however if we could see the component this function is in I could answer a lot more, however here is how you can check for null

```
    const addtoproduction = () => {

    let databaseChanges = unitTestsData.map(tests => { 
    return {
      "unit_test_id": tests.unit_test_template_id,
      "databases": tests.databases
    }
  })
    setAddRemoveDatabaseChanges(databaseChanges)
  
  if(AddRemoveDatabaseMode !== null && AddRemoveDatabaseMode === 'ADD'){
    console.log('added data', AddRemoveDatabaseChanges);

  } else if (AddRemoveDatabaseMode !== null && AddRemoveDatabaseMode === 'REMOVE') {
    console.log('removed data', AddRemoveDatabaseChanges )

  }
  }
```